# MsAccess - Combobox inputs ID into table instead of the text I want it too

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm using a combobox in a Ms Access form that gets it options from a separate table. I want it to be used by end users to input data into a table. Said data needs to be without errors because a 3rd party program (Qlik) will read the table contents and create a report on our workers and their "statistics".
I figured I want a dropdown menu, but when I use the combobox it input the ID of the text instead of the text itself.

Is there a way to have a dropdown menu in a Ms Access form that will input text into my table.

PS: I don't know if it's relevant but Ms Access is only being used as a front end for end-users. the data all ends up in a MySQL database.

I've looked at all the options I could find and I've been googling for a while but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Well, you are supposed to save the ID and not repetitively store the text. That's the way relational databases are supposed to work. Are you saving into a number or text field? If you don't want the ID then don't include it in the combobox RowSource.

Comment: I know that's what is supposed to happen and I've tried to explain it to my employer, but he needs Qlik to be able to read the database so he is allright with commiting more storage to repetitvely store the text. I'm saving into a VARCHAR255 field. the ID is already excluded. I want it to input the text instead of an ID related to said text.

Comment: If RowSource does not include ID then how is it saved? Makes no sense. And if you don't save ID, how are tables to be properly related? You define text field as primary key? How does Qlik read db - does it establish a connection? Can it pull data from query? Can Qlik build query?

Comment: From what I just read, Qlik can work with queries joining tables. No reason to bastardize your data structure.

Comment: I might have the wrong idea of what a rowsource is. I just checked it and I was thinking of the "hide key column (recommended)" option in the combobox wizard. Qlik reads the database through an ODBC connection. I don't know much more about it than that. I don't think it can create queries or anything like that.

Comment: RowSource is combobox property that pulls fields from table. You and your employer are setting yourselves up for a nightmare. Build the database properly. Qlik will handle it.

Comment: oh I know it will be a nightmare. I'm not sure if Qlik will be able to handle it but I'll try to figure it out. thank you for your help, it is appreciated.

Comment: Wait, Qlik actually has to connect to MySQL. But same situation. Use Qlik interface to connect and build queries.

Comment: You need a better understanding of the products you use or must be compatible with. In 5 minutes of web search, I conclude Qlik can build queries. I saw several examples documenting this with MySQL and Access, including on Qlik site. From a tutorial site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qlikview/qlikview_joins.htm#:~:text=Joins%20in%20QlikView%20are%20used%20to,to%20first%20learn%20about%20them%20here.&text=Joins%20in%20QlikView%20are,learn%20about%20them%20here.&text=QlikView%20are%20used%20to,to%20first%20learn%20about

Comment: I have a fairly good understanding of the products I use. I didn't hear anything about qlik until the database was near completion; that kind of messed everything up. What could be the use case of a Qlik query?

Comment: If I manually add the values I want to the combobox it's no longer a reference to another place in the database so it will input the text instead of an ID. It's the easiest fix I've found. thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Combobox RowSource could be a query like: `SELECT CompName FROM Companies;` - no ID field is included and descriptive text would be saved.

Comment: Unfortunately Adriaan felt the need to rollback my edit on the post. I have found that if I type in the required data manually it will not be a reference to another table and will not need an ID; it simply inputs the data I want.

Comment: Type data where - in combobox RowSource as a value list? If you allow free entry into a textbox, that will guarantee misspellings and your data will be garbage. Again, build the db properly or suffer.

Comment: "What could be the use case of a Qlik query?" - whatever you want. I don't know your database nor what 'statistics' are desired.

Comment: production department has to put in how many time they spend on doing a certain task and how much the processed in that time. but I've fixed it. thanks.

Comment: just now saw you other comment. I know, that's why I didn't allow text boxes. you seem to dance around the fact that I already have a solution though... I simply added the required values to the combo box manually so it doesn't refer to another part of the database thus doesn't input an ID but the actual text I want to see.

Comment: Are you saying you built a Value List for combobox RowSource? So how many companies are there?